# What is better "which" or "that"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, that-vs-which

Well, I've had a doubt for use *which* and *that*. Tell me if these examples are correct:

> This is the hot dog **which** I made.
>
> This is the hot dog **that** I made.
>
> I'm finding the DVD **which** I lost.
>
> I'm finding the DVD **that** I lost.

And also tell me what are the differences between *which* and *that*.

Comment: Before you ask a question, please try to search the site to see if it's already been answered :) You get your answers faster that way, and we have a cleaner site! :)

Comment: Sorry :) I forgot of search this question before of post, because I'm beginner here... the next question I will search before... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between using *which* and *that* is the difference between *non-restrictive* and *restrictive* clauses. A non-restrictive clause adds information to the sentence to clarify what it follows, but isn't required for understanding the sentence. A restrictive clause, by contrast, narrows the subset of items that the noun refers to, and as such, is necessary for full understanding of the sentence.

In your examples, you are referring to *specific* items -- there is only one hot dog made by you, only one DVD lost by you -- so you want to use *that* in these cases.

> This is the hot dog that I made (as opposed to all of the other hot dogs here).
>
> I'm finding the DVD that I lost (because I know where all my other ones are).

On the other hand, these examples are non-restrictive; they add clarifying information that can safely be removed without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> These hot dogs, which I made, are excellent. (The hot dogs are excellent; that I made them is tangential to that.)
>
> This DVD, which I lost, is my favorite one. (The fact that I lost it isn't necessary to understand that it's my favorite.)

Notice that "which" clauses are set off by commas, while "that" clauses aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Restrictive relative clauses can be introduced by that or which (or whose/who and variations thereof). These clauses introduce essential information about the noun (they restrict the meaning). "This is the hot dog that/which I made."

"The hot dog that/which I made tasted good" - The specific hot dog made by me, tasted good.

Non-restrictive relative clauses can be introduced by which (or whose/who and variations thereof). These clauses introduce non-essential information about the noun.

"The hot dog, which I made, tasted good" - The fact that I made the hot dog is not as important as in the above example, it's just extra information.